# How can i pass NSData object over Wifi network?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, wifi, nsdata

How can i pass NSData object over Wifi network? can any one provide me the code to send and receive the NSData over Wifi.or any sample code/app reference .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to send data in general, here is the code:

```
uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t)[myData bytes];
size_t length = [myData length];

sendBytesWithLength(bytes, length);
```

On the receiver side you regenerate your NSData object like this:

```
uint8_t *bytes = ; // Get the bytes from somewhere...
size_t length = ; // And the length

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:length];
```

Comment: may i know the code of receiver side(means:conversion of bytes to myData)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the Bonjour references in the first place to set up the connection? That should lead you on to the other options for network communication.